# How can I select all the occurence of a Username with numbers at the end?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a request to find all the occurence of a name in my Usernames table:

for example I have:

1. SAnderso
2. BBobby
3. SAnderso1
4. SAnderso2
5. SAnderso99

and I'd like to get all the SAnderso(here 1,3,4,5)

here's what I tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE NomUtilisateur LIKE 'SAnderso%[0123456789]' OR NomUtilisateur = 'SAnderso'
```

but when I do this nothing is shown in the results

can you help me ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In any database, this might do want you want:

```
WHERE NomUtilisateur LIKE 'SAnderso%'
```

If you specifically need to check for numbers after the name, then the method depends on the database.  In most databases, you'll need to use the extension for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In previous questions you have asked about MySQL so, assuming MySQL, you can use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) which allows regular expressions to be used:

```
SELECT * FROM Utilisateur
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NomUtilisateur, '^(SAnderso|SAnderso.*[0-9])$')
```

This is based on your attempt where you used `%` in `LIKE` so that there may be characters following "SAnderso" before the digit(s). If you only want "SAnderso" optionally followed by digits then you would change the regex pattern to `^SAnderso[0-9]*$`

Comment: I'm using mariadb 10 and it seems that it can use regex but REGEXP_LIKE doesn't exist do you know how to use regex on mariadb ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @mhawke who helped me find about REGEX in sql database the solution was to use it but in maria db REGEXP_LIKE does'nt exist so I looked on the documentation and foudn out I could do it like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE NomUtilisateur REGEXP '^(SAnderso|SAnderso.*[0-9])$'
```

Comment: It's always useful to look at the documentation first. In MYSQL REGEXP is a synonym for REGEXP_LIKE, i,e, they are the same. So your solution should work for both databases. There is also `RLIKE`, another synonym, supported by both databases.